# Installing Class::Inspector Perl module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am a windows 7 (64 bit) user. I was trying to install `Class::Inspector` module in Perl. However it requred `Nmake15.exe`. I have tried to download the exe and when I run it, there is an pop up message stating that

*The program or feature `Nmake15.exe` cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows*

Could anyone advice on this? Thanks. This is a pre-requisite module required by `SOAP::Lite`.

Comment: What kind of Perl are you using?

Comment: I am using ActivePerl 5.10.0 Build 1004

Answer (score 3):

nmake 1.5 is very old, and getting a modern version involves installing the massive Visual Studio suite.  As an alternative, you can use [dmake](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/dmake/) which works just as well.

In addition, your version of [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) is quite out of date.  I believe more recent versions now ship with a make program and will run much better on Windows.

Finally, [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) is in many ways a better distribution of Perl on Windows.  It comes with a complete Perl module build toolchain including dmake and a C compiler.  You should be able to install most modules on CPAN using its preconfigured CPAN shell.

Answer (score 0):

Class::Inspector is a pure-Perl module. Therefore, you could easily install it by copying the contents of the lib/ directory into one of your @INC paths.

This does not solve your problem with installing modules in general, though. That's why you should install a 64 bit version of nmake. By installing the Windows SDK, the nmake utility will be available at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio...\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.exe" ([microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585739/where-to-find-nmake-exe-for-64-bit-used-on-visual-studio-2008-professional-edition)).